# How to print rows where table names contains object in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

How do I print rows where table names contains object, here printing of `'A.arrival'` is not happening.

```
echo "arrival :" .$row['A.arrival'] ."."
```

Comment: Could you, please, supply the output of `var_dump($row);` to the question? It is not clear what is in your resultset. Also, is there any erros, that happening ?

Comment: What database and API are you using? Usually the table name is not included in the keys in the result set.

Comment: And aliases, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most database APIs don't include the table name in the associative array keys. So you should just use `$row['arrival']`.

If your query is returning two `arrival` columns from different tables, you should give one or both of them a different alias, e.g.

```
SELECT a.arrival AS a_arrival, b.arrival AS b_arrival, ...
```

Then you can refer to them as `$row['a_arrival']` and `$row['b_arrival']`.